How to config 2fa authentication for svn server with openldap
Currently I am using svn server authenticated by openldap running both on centos 7 server. Now I want to set up 2fa authentication for svn server. I have investigated and found some solution, and integration between openldap and mod_auth_mollen or keycloak, but I stil feel quite confuse about step to do this. Does anyone have the suggestion. Please help me.
Many thanks
